# Hide Titlebar when mouse is idle - Swift (Cocoa OS X)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, avplayer, avplayerview

In my Application, I'm trying to make it so that my AVPlayerView hides the titlebar when the mouse is idle.

Screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMcrv.png

Basically I want the the same effect the video controls have in which it automatically disappears if no mouse activity.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtTtb.png

Here is what I have right now:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    self.view.window?.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
    self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false
    self.view.window?.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask
}
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably set an `NSTimer` that would determine how long before the titlebar disappears. This would get invalidated and reset every time `mouseMoved:` is called. Once it gets called, then the only way I know to make an `NSWindow` titlebar fade out is to get the titlebar view through looping or using the superview of the button (of course it could always change later):

`[[[[self.window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] superview] animator] setAlphaValue:0];`

The titlebar buttons still work, so you'll have to group it in an `NSAnimationContext` and `setHidden:` when the animation completes.

Comment: Not a bad idea I'll give it a go! Thanks

Comment: This is an old topic and a smart answer, but did you figure out how to hide the border under title bar, too?